# ArcGIS COM API Error

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcfm

i am using the arcGIS api to make a plugin for arcFM, when i try to run this code

```
 Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef");
                System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                pApp = obj as IApplication;
```

i get

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x8000FFFF): Creating an instance of the component with CLSID {Appref CLSID HERE} from the IClassFactory faileddue to the following error: 8000ffff
```

Comment: Can you do a createinstance on other Esri types (e.g. esriGeometry.Point), or just having problems with AppRef?

Comment: Is this in a dll project? I wouldn't expect it to work in an exe project.

Comment: What kind of ArcFM extension are you developing? Is it an autoupdater? If that's the case, you should never rely on the IApplication being present since AUs can also be run in different context than an ESRI desktop application.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might not have initialized the ESRI ArcObjects libraries. You have to do that, to get your license set. You need to check here; [ESRI Library](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000006000000) to make sure you are getting the libraries started up properly.

Comment: I am using the example code from MMStartup.cs and the exact same code seems to work fine there

Comment: Ok, Looks like I missed this - '{Appref CLSID HERE}' - to me this is looking like its not seeing your extension being registerd with ArcGIS, so it may be trying to get to your custom code and isn't knowing what to start up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are running the code within an ESRI-app process (e.g. ArcMap, ArcCatalog), if you need to get a reference to a running IApplication from a standalone application, you can use the [AppROT](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000007000000) class.

Comment: how do i use the AppROT class?